# I have a Div with id And I want to detect out side of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i detect outside of div and javascript detect it.

```
<script>
    function detect(){
        alert("Detect");
    }
    //How to detect click outside of div
</script>
<div id="detect" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red;" onClick="detect()"></div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use jquery, in your script tag do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').click(function(e){
     if($(e.target).is('#detect')){
        return;
     }

     /// code goes here
  });
});
```

Comment: Why always $(document).ready(function(){ is not working? any script to use with it?

Comment: No i dont know how to use it. I already try to copy files and put the script in. can you please define so i can.

Comment: you can either user cdn by adding this script line <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> or download the jquery js file to your computer and link the script tag to it. here you'll find more information: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: why it detect on click at #detect ??? If i click on div it doesn't have to detect it but out of div.

Comment: try removing the onClick from the div

Comment: Yes i have remove it but still if i click out or in it detects both but i want to detect outside not on the div #detect.

Comment: It takes one time value and repeat the value again the same.

Comment: i don't understand your last comment. look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6nwfcqjx/1/ isn't it what you mean?